# How to recover photos from iPhone 7 deleted via Windows Explorer?

Tags: photos, windows, data-recovery, iphone, file-recovery

My mom deleted some photos from an iPhone 7.
She deleted them via Windows Explorer.
There is no backup as she took them just a few days ago.
Is it possible to recover them?

Thanks.

---

iPhone spec: iOS 10.0.3

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

Recovering files deleted from an encrypted hardware device is generally considered *not possible*, especially as they didn't go through iOS Photos' own deletion system, which would have kept them for 30 days.